# How do you use apoc.refactor.cloneSubgraph to clone a graph in neo4j

Tags: neo4j-apoc

I couldn't find a documentation or an example anywhere.

I created a graph and added the property

```
example:1
```

in all my nodes.

Now I want to make an exact copy of this graph with the only difference of making this property equal to 2

```
example:2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to define how to fetch this sub-graph. Assuming it's a star-graph identified by a central node with name 'center' you would use something like this:

```
Match path=(s{name: 'center')-->(n)
With collect(path) as paths
Call apoc.refactor.cloneSubgraphFromPaths(paths)
Yield input, output
With output
Set output.example = 2
Return output
```

The `With` clause can be used multiple times to alter the cloned graph. If your initial graph is not a star-shaped graph you simply need to change the first 'Match' clause corresponding to your case.